# Jquery for when navbar is at top of screen become sticky not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get the navbar (which is in front of a slideshow) to become sticky when it reaches the top of the page. Whenever it gets close to the top it jumps downwards slightly (to be under the slideshow) and does not become sticky at the top of the screen.

I am very inexperienced with Jquery so haven't tried anything different.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var stickyNavTop = $('nav').offset().top;
  console.log("work");
  var stickyNav = function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {
      $('nav').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
      $('nav').removeClass('sticky');
    }
  };

  stickyNav();

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    stickyNav();
  });
});
```

```css
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  border-top: 0;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #083867;
  font-family: Arial;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
}

.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img class="slideshow-image" src="http://placehold.it/1900x1080" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img class="slideshow-image" src="http://placehold.it/1900x1080" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <img class="slideshow-image" src="http://placehold.it/1900x1080" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">About</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="about.html">About us</a>
            <a href="nco-profile.html">NCO Profiles</a>
            <a href="co-profile.html">CO profiles</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="joinInfo.html">Joining Info</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link " href="calendar.html">Calendar</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="forms.html">Forms</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="courses.html">Courses</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="courses.html">Support Committee</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

The navbar when it reaches the top of the screen is supposed to gain the class sticky and stay at the top of the screen. When I scroll down to where the navbar would be at the top of the screen it jumps below the slideshow and does not become sticky.

Comment: Use `position:fixed` instead of `sticky`. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code will help you, you just add id ="header" to container class div and add jquery code which is in a bottom.

```
    <style>
     .sticky {
       position: sticky;  width: 100%;
       left: 0; top: 0;
       z-index: 100; border-top: 0;
     }

     .navbar {
       background-color: #083867; font-family: Arial;
       display: flex; justify-content: center;
       bottom: 0; position: absolute;
       z-index: 10; width: 100%;
     }

    .slideshow-container {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
    }
  </style>

 <body>

  <header>
    <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img class="slideshow-image" src="http://placehold.it/1900x1080" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img class="slideshow-image" src="http://placehold.it/1900x1080" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img class="slideshow-image" src="http://placehold.it/1900x1080" style="width:100%">
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container" id="header">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">About</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="about.html">About us</a>
                <a href="nco-profile.html">NCO Profiles</a>
                <a href="co-profile.html">CO profiles</a>
                </div>
            </div>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="joinInfo.html">Joining Info</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link " href="calendar.html">Calendar</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="forms.html">Forms</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="courses.html">Courses</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="courses.html">Support Committee</a>
                </li>
          </ul>  
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>


   <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      var HeaderTop = $('#header').offset().top;
      var hh =HeaderTop + 300;

      $(window).scroll(function(){
      if( $(window).scrollTop() > HeaderTop ) {
      if($(window).scrollTop() > hh) {
      $('#header').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px', background:'#083867', width:'100%'});   
      } else{
       $('#header').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});  
      }
      } else {
      $('#header').css({position: 'static'});
      }
    });
   });
  </script> 

 </body>
```

Comment: This solves the problem of the navbar jumping however the Jquery still doesn't keep the navbar at the top of the screen after scrolling down.

Comment: Hi, @Badgerous have you added the id="header" into the div class container like in my answer, <div class="container" id="header">.

Comment: Turns out there was an error on my end as I did not add the "after the header. So it now works, however, the navbar now takes up the entire screen when you scroll down to this point. It also jumps bellow the slideshow agan and doesn't return to its starting position but the position underneath the slideshow. What would I do to fix this @Sandeep?

Comment: Hi, @Sandeep I have fixed the problem of the navbar taking up the screen by removing the bottom: 0; css tag. The navbar now resides under the slideshow.

Comment: Hello, @Badgerous, first of all very sorry for the late reply,  I am happy to see that your problem is solved. Keep it up.  :)